# The effect of Wearing Contact Lenses during Working hours

Tags: eye, lenses

I always hated wearing my glasses. I find them cumbersome, reduce visibility since most of the time they're smudged, they tend to fall off with certain movements (like hugging your dog), etc...

I was wondering whether there are any negative side effects to wearing dailies for work and when venturing outside the house. I currently use DAILIES TOTAL1 but only wear them during the weekends.